# Python - Answer is alway same regardless of user input

Tags: python-3.x, list

I just started learning python and was trying simple projects. No matter what I put, rock, paper or scissors, it always returns 'Tie'. What am I missing?

[image]

Comment: You list choices are capitalized "Rock, Paper, Scissors" but the "if" statements for the random_decision are checking lowercase "rock, paper, scissors." When checking, you should cast to lower() to make sure it is equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Character cases matter when you compare text in Python. Instead of

```
decision == 'rock'
```

try,

```
decision.lower() == 'rock'
```

and see if that works.

Best of luck on your pursuit!

Answer (score 0):

Prabesh has the correct approach, but in Mitchell's case, the list choices are capitalized. Everything should be cast to lower() to make sure it is all equal including random_decision

```
decision = decision.lower()
random_decision = random.choice(list).lower()

# now do the if/else checking as normal
if decision == 'rock' and random_decision == 'paper':

    etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a simple mistake in your code.
In the list every element has first alphabet uppercase, but while checking you are comparing it with all the lowercase and as we know string literal or any literal for that matter is case sensitive, you are not getting match with any of the statements.

So either convert your decision to lower case while you are checking or just compare it with correct literals.

`decision.lower() == 'rock'`

or

`decision == 'Rock'`